# How to highlight selected menu in a vertical navbar coded in a Site.Master?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to code a navbar and I want to add the "active" class to the link when you are on the selected page.

I've tried several options using js and none worked for me. I'm not an expert so I'm trying my best. Here's the navbar code:

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./Inicio.aspx">
            <span data-feather="home"></span>
            Inicio
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./Push.aspx">
            <span data-feather="message-square"></span>
            Push a un cliente
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./LoadDocuments.aspx">
            <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
            Carga de documentos
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./LoadExcel.aspx">
            <span data-feather="upload"></span>
            Carga de fichero Excel
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./GestEmail.aspx">
            <span data-feather="mail"></span>
            Gestión del correo
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./ImgVehiculos.aspx">
            <span data-feather="image"></span>
            Carga de imágenes
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So far what I got was just highlighting the name with the data-toggle="pill", but that's not what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an inline ternary operator that checks for the RawUrl.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link <%= Request.RawUrl.Contains("Inicio.aspx") ? "active" : "" %>" href="./Inicio.aspx">
        <span data-feather="message-square"></span>
        Inicio
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, but it's not working... I am missing something? do I need to reference something before?

Comment: No, it should work as is. What is the result is you put it directly on the page `<%= Request.RawUrl.Contains("Inicio.aspx") %>`

Comment: Nothing happens, still not highlighted. Does the nav-link class affect?

.sidebar .nav-link {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #ffffff;
}

Comment: Does the active class get added. If so you need to add css for that class.

Comment: Yes it is...      .sidebar .nav-link.active {
        color: #007bff;